# Downcasting vs. a Passthrough Method

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

When you want to implement an interface and still inherit a base class with shared methods, is there a preferred or best practice way of accessing the base class methods?  Rather than having a Select Case checking the type of the derived class, is it also acceptable to just use pass-through methods as below?

(This is not a real project, I tried to simplify the question as much as possible by creating as small of an example as I could -- so it may not be the best way to use such functionality.)

```
Public Class Form1
Dim obj As ICharacter

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    obj = New Fighter
    obj.Attack()
    obj.Say("I am a fighter!")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    obj = New Mage
    obj.Attack()
    obj.Say("I am a mage!")
End Sub
End Class

Interface ICharacter
Sub Attack()
Sub Say(ByVal Dialogue As String)
End Interface

Public Class BaseCharacter
Public Shared Sub Say(ByVal Dialogue As String)
    Debug.WriteLine(Dialogue)
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Fighter
Inherits BaseCharacter
Implements ICharacter

Public Sub Attack() Implements ICharacter.Attack
    Debug.WriteLine("This class swings a sword!")
End Sub

Public Overloads Sub Say(ByVal Dialogue As String) Implements ICharacter.Say
    BaseCharacter.Say(Dialogue)
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Mage
Inherits BaseCharacter
Implements ICharacter

Public Sub Attack() Implements ICharacter.Attack
    Debug.WriteLine("This class casts a spell!")
End Sub

Public Overloads Sub Say(ByVal Dialogue As String) Implements ICharacter.Say
    BaseCharacter.Say(Dialogue)
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm looking for alternatives to something like:

```
If TypeOf obj Is Mage Then
  CType(obj, Mage).Say("I am a mage!")
ElseIf TypeOf obj Is Fighter Then
  CType(obj, Fighter).Say("I am a fighter!")
End If
```

or:

```
Select Case obj.GetType()
  Case GetType(Mage)
    CType(obj, Mage).Say("I am a mage!")
  Case GetType(Fighter)
    CType(obj, Fighter).Say("I am a fighter!")
End Select
```

Comment: Where would you implement this logic? A calling class or inside the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base class could contain a Type, and the New of each class would set that value. This would prevent you from doing a GetType in your case.

```
Public Class BaseCharacter
  Enum TypeOfCharacter
     Mage
     Fighter
  End Enum

  Public Property Type As TypeOfCharacter

  Public Shared Sub Say(ByVal Dialogue As String)
      Debug.WriteLine(Dialogue)
  End Sub
End Class
```

You could then have a dictionary for your strings.

```
   Dim speech As New Dictionary(Of BaseCharacter.TypeOfCharacter, String)

   speech.Add(BaseCharacter.TypeOfCharacter.Mage, "I am a mage!")
   speech.Add(BaseCharacter.TypeOfCharacter.Fighter, "I am a fighter!")

   obj.Say(speech(obj.Type))
```

But in your example, the string could easely be inside the actual class.

```
Public Class Fighter
  Inherits BaseCharacter
  Implements ICharacter

  Public Overloads Sub SayName()
     BaseCharacter.Say("I am a fighter!")
   End Sub
End Class

Public Class Mage
  Inherits BaseCharacter
  Implements ICharacter

  Public Overloads Sub SayName()
    BaseCharacter.Say("I am a mage!")
  End Sub
End Class
```